# visual studio timer ticks displayed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is my code for my drag race but I am wondering, I have my timer but how do I place it on a label?

```
private void tmrRaceTimerNamo_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //car speed
    pcbCar1Namo.Left = pcbCar1Namo.Left + 10;
    pcbCar2Namo.Left = pcbCar2Namo.Left + 4;
    pcbCar3Namo.Left = pcbCar3Namo.Left + 5;
    pcbCar4Namo.Left = pcbCar4Namo.Left + 7;

    //car stops at finish
    AllCarsOnFinishNamo();
}

private void AllCarsOnFinishNamo()
{
    if (pcbCar1Namo.Left > pcbFininshNamo.Right)
    {
        pcbCar1Namo.Left = pcbFininshNamo.Right;
    }

    if (pcbCar2Namo.Left > pcbFininshNamo.Right)
    {
        pcbCar2Namo.Left = pcbFininshNamo.Right;
        tmrRaceTimerNamo.Enabled = false;
    }

    if (pcbCar3Namo.Left > pcbFininshNamo.Right)
    {
        pcbCar3Namo.Left = pcbFininshNamo.Right;
    }

    if (pcbCar4Namo.Left > pcbFininshNamo.Right)
    {
        pcbCar4Namo.Left = pcbFininshNamo.Right;
    }
}

private void btnGoNamo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //start of timer 
    tmrRaceTimerNamo.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to place on a label?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the label to the value on each tick or update. For example in your `tmrRaceTimerNamo_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)` method, you can set the labels text property to the time.

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly know what you want to show but i think you want to see the fps you are getting while playing your drag race game so here is a function for afps counter

```
private static int lastTick;
    private static int lastFrameRate;
    private static int frameRate;

    public static int CalculateFrameRate()
    {
        label.Text = CalculateFrameRate().ToString();
        if (System.Environment.TickCount - lastTick >= 1000)
        {
            lastFrameRate = frameRate;
            frameRate = 0;
            lastTick = System.Environment.TickCount;
        }
        frameRate++;
        return lastFrameRate;
    }
```